# How to set a translucent background for a layout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

My application has a class that extends Relative Layout. I would like to know if there is any way in which I can make the background of this class translucent programmatically. Since its not an activity I cannot set the style attribute in the Manifest file to "Translucent" and I cannot use the setAlpha() method too since the setAlpha() method is applicable from API Level 11 onwards and my application has an API Level of 11 and due to certain restrictions I cannot change it to API Level 11. Could you please guide me in this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `setBackgroundResource` or `setBackgroundColor`. I think first is pretty simple.

Second one takes an `int` as an argument. So, just convert your hex color (for example `#55000000`) into decimal and it will work as well.

However, it's better to use `setBackgroundResource`, because in this case you store your colors in separate file:

```
setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor);
setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
//etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I cannot use the setBackgroundResource() method too because my application is a library project and due to certain restrictions we are not to use any resources from the "res" folder.

Comment: @IngridCooper your application should be an Android Library (as, for example, `ActionBarSherlock`). In this case you can use resources. By the way, if your application works with Android SDK, it's definately should be Android Library.

Comment: The problem is in our application we are not supposed to access the resource "res" folder at all. Hence, we have written all our xmls programmatically in classes. So I will have to use the second option only by using the setBackgroundColor() method.